# Whitelist BigQuery IP address

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to establish a connection between AWS and Bigquery transfer service, however, due to firewall blocking bigquery, I couldn't establish the access.
Where can I get the list of bigquery IP addresses?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the official *BigQuery Data Transfer* [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/transfer-service-overview) connection to the particular service [API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/) can be established via specific external endpoint URL:

> A **service endpoint** is a base URL that specifies the network
>   address of an API service. One service may have multiple service
>   endpoints. This service has the following service endpoint and all
>   URIs below are relative to this service endpoint:
>
> https://bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com